# why doesn't Xcode 8.3.2 show immediate syntax error while editing

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

Recently i downloaded Xcode of the latest version. But to my surprise, there was no immediate syntax error warning while i was editing. How to make it show that warning again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places in Xcode's settings that control this behavior: a global setting for the editor, and another setting for each project.

For the global setting, go to the menubar and choose `Xcode -> Preferences...`. Click the tab for `General`, then make sure the box for `Show live issues` is checked.[image: Xcode general preferences]

For the project settings, with your project open go to `File -> Project Settings...` then check the box next to `Show live issues for source code`.

[image: Xcode project settings]

Comment: I just found the answer to this question. To make it work, i have to check both the "show live  issues" in project setting as well as the one in Preference > General ...Thanks!!

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't there also a Xcode global settings for this?

Comment: @JiaLi Oops sorry I missed that! I added it to the answer for future viewers.